# Puppet can't find data item from hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm trying to build a Hiera configuration for my Puppet setup. My Hosts are FreeBSD and Debian systems. Therefore I have a configuration based on `::osfamily`. But since I'm making extensive use of Jails I would like to have a further breakdown of my FreeBSD hosts with `::virtual`.

from **hiera.yaml**:

```
:hierarchy:
    - "osfamily/%{::osfamily}"
    - "%{::virtual}/%{::osfamily}"
    - common
```

And my data directory tree:

```
hieradata/
|-- common.yaml
|-- osfamily
|   |-- Debian.yaml
|   `-- FreeBSD.yaml
|-- physical
|   `-- FreeBSD.yaml
|-- jailed
`-- virtual
```

In my understandigs puppet should apply everything **osfamily/FreeBSD.yaml** and afterwards from **physical/FreeBSD.yaml** for a physical FreeBSD host.

Now I want to install the CA-Certificates package on every host and have a class for that task:

```
class certificates ( $packageName = hiera('ca_package') ){

  # Install CA-Certificates
  package { $packageName:
    ensure   => installed,
  }
}
```

That class is included from **common.yaml**

```
classes:
    - certificates
```

And the *ca_package*-Variable is defined in **osfamily/FreeBSD.yaml**:

```
---
rootuser: root
rootgroup: wheel
sshservicename: sshd
ca_package: 'security/ca_root_nss'
```

When I do a hiera test on that variable, everything is working fine:

```
# hiera -c /usr/local/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml ca_package ::osfamily=FreeBSD
security/ca_root_nss
#
```

But Puppet is (even in Jails) complaining, that the data item `ca_package` is not available.

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Could not find data item ca_package in any Hiera data file and
>   no default supplied at
>   /usr/local/etc/puppet/modules/certificates/manifests/init.pp:2 on node
>   puppet.fqdn

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you put `notify { "Virtual: ${::virtual} ... Osfamily: ${::osfamily}": }` in your node definition, and then refresh your puppet agent. This will confirm both of those facts are what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug hiera is using below command:

```
puppet master --debug --compile hostname --osfamily=FreeBSD |grep hiera
```

look for the key `ca_package`, then you should know how to fix.

Second, your hostname is `puppet.fqdn`, which is weird for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the facter variable 'osfamily' on your client is 'FreeBSD'. Alternatively you can enable debug on puppetserver (logback.xml) and see the log to see which hierarchy its going through and where its failing to get the ca_package.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug Hiera is running `lookup` command on Puppet server node:

```
$ puppet lookup --environment production --explain --node fqdn.example.com ca_package
```

where `ca_package` is the hiera key you're looking for. The `--explain` flag is helpful for verifying paths were Puppet is looking for the key.

Also merge behavior can be manually defined:

```
puppet lookup --merge deep --environment production --node fqdn.example.com
```